# Solr makes index but solarium doesn't index more than 9 documents

Tags: solr, solarium

I am working on Ubuntu. I want to use Solarium to index documents in Solr. When I try to index documents via Solarium it indexes at most 9 documents at a time, so I can't add new documents, but when I try to index new documents from shell it works ok.

```
$$config = array(
    'endpoint' => array(
        'localhost' => array(
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'port' => 8983,
            'path' => '/solr/',
            'core' => 'collection1'

        )
    )
);


// create a client instance
$client = new Solarium\Client($config);

$update = $client->createUpdate();
$doc1 = $update->createDocument();

$doc1->id = 500;


$doc1->text ='هل هو التعاطف الإنساني مع شخصية فذة، وعبقرية مؤكدة أحاط بها التآمر من كل جانب، مسلمين ومسيحيين ويهود، فطمروها وطمروا فكرها تحت غبار القرون، حتى أصبح فكر ابن رشد وموسى بن ميمون، وهما أقل منه قامة، يدرس في أوروبا في الوقت الذي تم فيه تهميش فكر ابن حزم حتى   كاد  أن يندثر لولا أن قيض الله له أحد المستشرقين المنصفين وهو';



// Create another doc
$doc2 = $update->createDocument();
$doc2->id = 501;

$doc2->text ='موضوع الدراسة وأهدافها ومنهجها
لماذا ابن حزم، في الوقت الذي يزخر فيه تاريخنا الإسلامي والعربي بعشرات بل وبمئات العلماء، قديمًا وحديثًا، والذين وضعوا بصمتهم في كل المناحي العلمية والأدبية، ولم يقتصر تأثيرهم على الدائرة الإسلامية أو العربية فقط، بل تعداها إلى أوروبا التي كانت تغط- قبلهم- في سبات عميق.
فلماذا ابن حزم إذًا؟؟:';

//$doc2->id_page = 333; 

$doc3 = $update->createDocument();
$doc3->id = 502;

$doc3->text ='عندما نشر كتابه (تاريخ أسبانيا)    عام 1861م.
وقد يمثل هذا جانبًا من أسباب اختياري لابن حزم، لكنه لا يقدم الإجابة الكاملة عن السؤال:
لماذا ابن حزم تحديدًا؟؟
إذا كان هناك العديد من الدراسات والأطروحات عن ابن حزم وفكره التي أضاءت جوانب من تراثه الضخم، وأبرزت عبقرية وعقلية نادرة المثال، فأني بدوري أراه- ومن زاوية أحسب أنها مختلفة- واحدًا من أعظم رواد التنوير في ثقافتنا الإسلامية، التنوير الذي يؤسس للعقل والعقلانية، ويعتمد (النص) إطارًا مرجعيًا، مقدمًا منهجًا- لا مذهبًا- واضح المعالم، مستوفيًا أدوات البحث';


$doc4 = $update->createDocument();
$doc4->id = 503;

$doc4->text ='ali cmso sajh';


$doc5 = $update->createDocument();
$doc5->id = 504;

$doc5->text = 'روان';


//$doc3->id_page = 333; 

$doc6 = $update->createDocument();
$doc6->id = 505;

$doc6->text ='عندما نشر كتابه (تاريخ أسبانيا)    عام 1861م.
وقد يمثل هذا جانبًا من أسباب اختياري لابن حزم، لكنه لا يقدم الإجابة الكاملة عن السؤال:
لماذا ابن حزم تحديدًا؟؟
إذا كان هناك العديد من الدراسات والأطروحات عن ابن حزم وفكره التي أضاءت جوانب من تراثه الضخم، وأبرزت عبقرية وعقلية نادرة المثال، فأني بدوري أراه- ومن زاوية أحسب أنها مختلفة- واحدًا من أعظم رواد التنوير في ثقافتنا الإسلامية، التنوير الذي يؤسس للعقل والعقلانية، ويعتمد (النص) إطارًا مرجعيًا، مقدمًا منهجًا- لا مذهبًا- واضح المعالم، مستوفيًا أدوات البحث';


$doc7 = $update->createDocument();
$doc7->id = 506;

$doc7->text ='عندما نشر كتابه (تاريخ أسبانيا)    عام 1861م.
وقد يمثل هذا جانبًا من أسباب اختياري لابن حزم، لكنه لا يقدم الإجابة الكاملة عن السؤال:
لماذا ابن حزم تحديدًا؟؟
إذا كان هناك العديد من الدراسات والأطروحات عن ابن حزم وفكره التي أضاءت جوانب من تراثه الضخم، وأبرزت عبقرية وعقلية نادرة المثال، فأني بدوري أراه- ومن زاوية أحسب أنها مختلفة- واحدًا من أعظم رواد التنوير في ثقافتنا الإسلامية، التنوير الذي يؤسس للعقل والعقلانية، ويعتمد (النص) إطارًا مرجعيًا، مقدمًا منهجًا- لا مذهبًا- واضح المعالم، مستوفيًا أدوات البحث';



$doc8 = $update->createDocument();
$doc8->id = 507;

$doc8->text ='عندما نشر كتابه (تاريخ أسبانيا)    عام 1861م.
وقد يمثل هذا جانبًا من أسباب اختياري لابن حزم، لكنه لا يقدم الإجابة الكاملة عن السؤال:
لماذا ابن حزم تحديدًا؟؟
إذا كان هناك العديد من الدراسات والأطروحات عن ابن حزم وفكره التي أضاءت جوانب من تراثه الضخم، وأبرزت عبقرية وعقلية نادرة المثال، فأني بدوري أراه- ومن زاوية أحسب أنها مختلفة- واحدًا من أعظم رواد التنوير في ثقافتنا الإسلامية، التنوير الذي يؤسس للعقل والعقلانية، ويعتمد (النص) إطارًا مرجعيًا، مقدمًا منهجًا- لا مذهبًا- واضح المعالم، مستوفيًا أدوات البحث';


$doc9 = $update->createDocument();
$doc9->id = 508;

$doc9->text ='عندما نشر كتابه (تاريخ أسبانيا)    عام 1861م.
وقد يمثل هذا جانبًا من أسباب اختياري لابن حزم، لكنه لا يقدم الإجابة الكاملة عن السؤال:
لماذا ابن حزم تحديدًا؟؟
إذا كان هناك العديد من الدراسات والأطروحات عن ابن حزم وفكره التي أضاءت جوانب من تراثه الضخم، وأبرزت عبقرية وعقلية نادرة المثال، فأني بدوري أراه- ومن زاوية أحسب أنها مختلفة- واحدًا من أعظم رواد التنوير في ثقافتنا الإسلامية، التنوير الذي يؤسس للعقل والعقلانية، ويعتمد (النص) إطارًا مرجعيًا، مقدمًا منهجًا- لا مذهبًا- واضح المعالم، مستوفيًا أدوات البحث';


$doc10 = $update->createDocument();
$doc10->id = 509;

$doc10->text ='عندما نشر كتابه (تاريخ أسبانيا)    عام 1861م.
وقد يمثل هذا جانبًا من أسباب اختياري لابن حزم، لكنه لا يقدم الإجابة الكاملة عن السؤال:
لماذا ابن حزم تحديدًا؟؟
إذا كان هناك العديد من الدراسات والأطروحات عن ابن حزم وفكره التي أضاءت جوانب من تراثه الضخم، وأبرزت عبقرية وعقلية نادرة المثال، فأني بدوري أراه- ومن زاوية أحسب أنها مختلفة- واحدًا من أعظم رواد التنوير في ثقافتنا الإسلامية، التنوير الذي يؤسس للعقل والعقلانية، ويعتمد (النص) إطارًا مرجعيًا، مقدمًا منهجًا- لا مذهبًا- واضح المعالم، مستوفيًا أدوات البحث';


$doc11 = $update->createDocument();
$doc11->id = 241;

$doc11->text ='عندما نشر كتابه (تاريخ أسبانيا)    عام 1861م.
وقد يمثل هذا جانبًا من أسباب اختياري لابن حزم، لكنه لا يقدم الإجابة الكاملة عن السؤال:
لماذا ابن حزم تحديدًا؟؟
إذا كان هناك العديد من الدراسات والأطروحات عن ابن حزم وفكره التي أضاءت جوانب من تراثه الضخم، وأبرزت عبقرية وعقلية نادرة المثال، فأني بدوري أراه- ومن زاوية أحسب أنها مختلفة- واحدًا من أعظم رواد التنوير في ثقافتنا الإسلامية، التنوير الذي يؤسس للعقل والعقلانية، ويعتمد (النص) إطارًا مرجعيًا، مقدمًا منهجًا- لا مذهبًا- واضح المعالم، مستوفيًا أدوات البحث';



$doc12 = $update->createDocument();
$doc12->id = 242;

$doc12->text ='عندما نشر كتابه (تاريخ أسبانيا)    عام 1861م.
وقد يمثل هذا جانبًا من أسباب اختياري لابن حزم، لكنه لا يقدم الإجابة الكاملة عن السؤال:
لماذا ابن حزم تحديدًا؟؟
إذا كان هناك العديد من الدراسات والأطروحات عن ابن حزم وفكره التي أضاءت جوانب من تراثه الضخم، وأبرزت عبقرية وعقلية نادرة المثال، فأني بدوري أراه- ومن زاوية أحسب أنها مختلفة- واحدًا من أعظم رواد التنوير في ثقافتنا الإسلامية، التنوير الذي يؤسس للعقل والعقلانية، ويعتمد (النص) إطارًا مرجعيًا، مقدمًا منهجًا- لا مذهبًا- واضح المعالم، مستوفيًا أدوات البحث';



$doc13 = $update->createDocument();
$doc13->id = 300;

$doc13->text ='عندما نشر كتابه (تاريخ أسبانيا)    عام 1861م.
وقد يمثل هذا جانبًا من أسباب اختياري لابن حزم، لكنه لا يقدم الإجابة الكاملة عن السؤال:
لماذا ابن حزم تحديدًا؟؟
إذا كان هناك العديد من الدراسات والأطروحات عن ابن حزم وفكره التي أضاءت جوانب من تراثه الضخم، وأبرزت عبقرية وعقلية نادرة المثال، فأني بدوري أراه- ومن زاوية أحسب أنها مختلفة- واحدًا من أعظم رواد التنوير في ثقافتنا الإسلامية، التنوير الذي يؤسس للعقل والعقلانية، ويعتمد (النص) إطارًا مرجعيًا، مقدمًا منهجًا- لا مذهبًا- واضح المعالم، مستوفيًا أدوات البحث';


$doc14 = $update->createDocument();
$doc14->id = 301;

$doc14->text ='عندما نشر كتابه (تاريخ أسبانيا)    عام 1861م.
وقد يمثل هذا جانبًا من أسباب اختياري لابن حزم، لكنه لا يقدم الإجابة الكاملة عن السؤال:
لماذا ابن حزم تحديدًا؟؟
إذا كان هناك العديد من الدراسات والأطروحات عن ابن حزم وفكره التي أضاءت جوانب من تراثه الضخم، وأبرزت عبقرية وعقلية نادرة المثال، فأني بدوري أراه- ومن زاوية أحسب أنها مختلفة- واحدًا من أعظم رواد التنوير في ثقافتنا الإسلامية، التنوير الذي يؤسس للعقل والعقلانية، ويعتمد (النص) إطارًا مرجعيًا، مقدمًا منهجًا- لا مذهبًا- واضح المعالم، مستوفيًا أدوات البحث';


$doc15 = $update->createDocument();
$doc15->id = 302;

$doc15->text ='عندما نشر كتابه (تاريخ أسبانيا)    عام 1861م.
وقد يمثل هذا جانبًا من أسباب اختياري لابن حزم، لكنه لا يقدم الإجابة الكاملة عن السؤال:
لماذا ابن حزم تحديدًا؟؟
إذا كان هناك العديد من الدراسات والأطروحات عن ابن حزم وفكره التي أضاءت جوانب من تراثه الضخم، وأبرزت عبقرية وعقلية نادرة المثال، فأني بدوري أراه- ومن زاوية أحسب أنها مختلفة- واحدًا من أعظم رواد التنوير في ثقافتنا الإسلامية، التنوير الذي يؤسس للعقل والعقلانية، ويعتمد (النص) إطارًا مرجعيًا، مقدمًا منهجًا- لا مذهبًا- واضح المعالم، مستوفيًا أدوات البحث';


$doc16 = $update->createDocument();
$doc16->id = 303;

$doc16->text ='عندما نشر كتابه (تاريخ أسبانيا)    عام 1861م.
وقد يمثل هذا جانبًا من أسباب اختياري لابن حزم، لكنه لا يقدم الإجابة الكاملة عن السؤال:
لماذا ابن حزم تحديدًا؟؟
إذا كان هناك العديد من الدراسات والأطروحات عن ابن حزم وفكره التي أضاءت جوانب من تراثه الضخم، وأبرزت عبقرية وعقلية نادرة المثال، فأني بدوري أراه- ومن زاوية أحسب أنها مختلفة- واحدًا من أعظم رواد التنوير في ثقافتنا الإسلامية، التنوير الذي يؤسس للعقل والعقلانية، ويعتمد (النص) إطارًا مرجعيًا، مقدمًا منهجًا- لا مذهبًا- واضح المعالم، مستوفيًا أدوات البحث';


$doc17 = $update->createDocument();
$doc17->id = 304;

$doc17->text ='عندما نشر كتابه (تاريخ أسبانيا)    عام 1861م.
وقد يمثل هذا جانبًا من أسباب اختياري لابن حزم، لكنه لا يقدم الإجابة الكاملة عن السؤال:
لماذا ابن حزم تحديدًا؟؟
إذا كان هناك العديد من الدراسات والأطروحات عن ابن حزم وفكره التي أضاءت جوانب من تراثه الضخم، وأبرزت عبقرية وعقلية نادرة المثال، فأني بدوري أراه- ومن زاوية أحسب أنها مختلفة- واحدًا من أعظم رواد التنوير في ثقافتنا الإسلامية، التنوير الذي يؤسس للعقل والعقلانية، ويعتمد (النص) إطارًا مرجعيًا، مقدمًا منهجًا- لا مذهبًا- واضح المعالم، مستوفيًا أدوات البحث';



$doc18 = $update->createDocument();
$doc18->id = 305;

$doc18->text ='عندما نشر كتابه (تاريخ أسبانيا)    عام 1861م.
وقد يمثل هذا جانبًا من أسباب اختياري لابن حزم، لكنه لا يقدم الإجابة الكاملة عن السؤال:
لماذا ابن حزم تحديدًا؟؟
إذا كان هناك العديد من الدراسات والأطروحات عن ابن حزم وفكره التي أضاءت جوانب من تراثه الضخم، وأبرزت عبقرية وعقلية نادرة المثال، فأني بدوري أراه- ومن زاوية أحسب أنها مختلفة- واحدًا من أعظم رواد التنوير في ثقافتنا الإسلامية، التنوير الذي يؤسس للعقل والعقلانية، ويعتمد (النص) إطارًا مرجعيًا، مقدمًا منهجًا- لا مذهبًا- واضح المعالم، مستوفيًا أدوات البحث';


$doc19 = $update->createDocument();
$doc19->id = 306;

$doc19->text ='عندما نشر كتابه (تاريخ أسبانيا)    عام 1861م.
وقد يمثل هذا جانبًا من أسباب اختياري لابن حزم، لكنه لا يقدم الإجابة الكاملة عن السؤال:
لماذا ابن حزم تحديدًا؟؟
إذا كان هناك العديد من الدراسات والأطروحات عن ابن حزم وفكره التي أضاءت جوانب من تراثه الضخم، وأبرزت عبقرية وعقلية نادرة المثال، فأني بدوري أراه- ومن زاوية أحسب أنها مختلفة- واحدًا من أعظم رواد التنوير في ثقافتنا الإسلامية، التنوير الذي يؤسس للعقل والعقلانية، ويعتمد (النص) إطارًا مرجعيًا، مقدمًا منهجًا- لا مذهبًا- واضح المعالم، مستوفيًا أدوات البحث';



$doc20 = $update->createDocument();
$doc20->id = 307;

$doc20->text ='عندما نشر كتابه (تاريخ أسبانيا)    عام 1861م.
وقد يمثل هذا جانبًا من أسباب اختياري لابن حزم، لكنه لا يقدم الإجابة الكاملة عن السؤال:
لماذا ابن حزم تحديدًا؟؟
إذا كان هناك العديد من الدراسات والأطروحات عن ابن حزم وفكره التي أضاءت جوانب من تراثه الضخم، وأبرزت عبقرية وعقلية نادرة المثال، فأني بدوري أراه- ومن زاوية أحسب أنها مختلفة- واحدًا من أعظم رواد التنوير في ثقافتنا الإسلامية، التنوير الذي يؤسس للعقل والعقلانية، ويعتمد (النص) إطارًا مرجعيًا، مقدمًا منهجًا- لا مذهبًا- واضح المعالم، مستوفيًا أدوات البحث';

//,$doc6,$doc7,$doc8,$doc9,$doc10,$doc11,$doc12,$doc13,$doc14,$doc15,$doc16,$doc17,$doc18,$doc19,$doc20));
$update->addDocuments(array($doc1,$doc2,$doc3,$doc4,$doc5));

$update->addCommit(); 
$rr=$client->update($update);

 echo $rr->getStatus().'<br>';

$update->addDeleteQuery('id:502');
$update->addCommit();
$client->update($update);


$update->addDocuments(array($doc6,$doc7,$doc8,$doc9,$doc10));

$update->addCommit(); $client->update($update);
echo $rr->getStatus().'<br>';

$update->addDocuments(array($doc11,$doc12,$doc13,$doc14,$doc15));

$update->addCommit(); $client->update($update);
echo $rr->getStatus().'<br>';

$update->addDocuments(array($doc16,$doc17,$doc18,$doc19,$doc20));

$update->addCommit(); $client->update($update);
echo $rr->getStatus().'<br>';
```

This is my PHP code. I am using Solarium 3.0.0 and Solr 4.7.2

Comment: What does the status say? Why do you have a `addDeleteQuery` in there? Does the Solr log show anything useful? You might also want to read up on using arrays in PHP to avoid having to have $doc1, $doc2, $doc3, etc. :-)

Comment: status say 0 that mean Success ,addDeleteQuery it just delete one document The problem arise before and after it :)

Comment: Are the IDs correctly stored in the index, is the id field defined as the uniqueKey? Does the same thing happen if you add the documents in the reverse order? (is it the same nine if you do things in reverse?)

Comment: .. and what does the Solr log say when you're adding the last ten documents?

Comment: thank you a lot the problem was the number of return rows not in indexing i solve it :)